# How to create a test for the below controller?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, jestjs, nestjs

do I need to write a test for the below code?

```
@Post()
    update(@Body() updateUserDto: UpdateUserDto, @Request() req) {
        return this.userService.update(req.user.user, updateUserDto);
      }
```

Comment: What are you wanting to test about it? The full HTTP endpoint, the unit test of the controller, something else about it?

Comment: i need just unit test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to make some assumptions about injected properties of the controller class. For full setups, you can view [my testing example repo here](https://github.com/jmcdo29/testing-nestjs). This should be essentially what you're looking for though

```js
describe('UserController (Unit)', () => {
  let controller: UserController;
  let service: MockedClass<UserService>;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    const modRef = await Test.createTestingModule({
      controllers: [UserController],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: UserService,
          useValue: {
            update: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({ hello: 'world' }),
          },
        }
      ],
    }).compile();
    controller = modRef.get(UserController);
    service = modRef.get(UserService);
  });
  it('should call update and return the value', () => {
    const bodyVal = objectThatMatchesUpdateUserDto;
    const reqVal = {
      user: {
        user: valueThatMatchesReqUserUser
      }
    };
    const res = controller.update(bodyVal, reqVal);
    expect(res).toEqual({ hello: 'world' });
    expect(service.update).toBeCalledWith(reqVal.user.user, bodyVal)
  });
});
```